# Is session_destroy() revelant on a login failed attempt?

Tags: php, authentication

I'm trying to create a **2FA email login page** and I am a bit doubtful about using `$_SESSION`.

**The process includes these steps in the following order :**

1. Make sure the `$_SESSION['isLoggedIn']` **is not set** *(cf. step 3)*
2. Verify that `$_POST['username'| 'password']` are the **same values** as those stored in database
3. In that case *if the password submitted by the user is correct*, set `$_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = false` (so the user trying to login cannot be redirected on the same page)
4. Redirect to a token checking page that generates and send a token to the user email address
5. Check if tokens are the **exact same values**

   - If it's correct, set `$_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true`
   - If **not**, call `session_destroy()` ?
6. Redirect the user at the initial form in case of error

**Are there any better solutions concerning this case ?**

Thanking you in advance for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not setting other values in a page before in your session this could be a valid thing to do. But remember: The session will be completely stopped, so other values you have set before will be deleted

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Correct me if i'm wrong, assuming two users are trying to login at the same time but one of them fails, the second user should be affected as well ? (until his `$_SESSION['id']` is not set ?)

Comment: @tama No, a session is per user, so if you do something with 1 person his session, the other sessions won't be affected

Comment: yes, sorry for that @Timberman, I didn't read your first answer correctly, thanks again !